# Нет памяти на запуск SSH

Tags: ssh, vps

Задался вопросом, а не обманывает ли часом меня компания, предоставившая за мои кровные мне VPS. Суть проблемы:
Давеча отвалился SSH. Оказалось, остановился сервер SSH. Попытка запуска окончилась выдачей ошибки:

```
Failed to start service :

/etc/init.d/ssh: xmalloc: ../bash/parse.y:5874: cannot allocate 394264557 bytes (1073799168 bytes allocated)
```

Короче, что-то про память.
Отключил все основные сервисы, кроме BIND DNS Server, ситуация повторилась.
По статистике работающих процессов имеется итог:

> Real memory: 1024 MB total / 984.53 MB free / 252.34 MB cached   Swap space: 256 MB total / 175.56 MB free

Почти вся память свободна, но по уверениям техподдержки не хватает памяти и надо повышать план. Логичен вопрос в моей голове, а как же изначально этот SSH сервер запустился в принципе? Уж ли не обманывают ли меня, вынуждая отдать им больше деньжат?

Вот еще проблема. К сожалению, я всего лишь посредственный пхп-программист и в линукс-администрировании профан-профаном. Но вот скрин из файлового менеджера. Наверху часть файлов с датой от 21 октября. Не являются ли они странными? Да и сам файл ssh 300 мб весит. Это нормально?

[image]

Comment: @Димка, если вас не затруднит, укажите потом главного героя этой истории.

Comment: Да, если ребята не смогут или не захотят ответить на пару моих "албанских" вопросов, то придется с ними расстаться. А может даже написать короткий роман о наших "отношениях" :)))

Comment: @Димка, технологии виртуализации в принципе позволяют запустить число машин с большим общим количеством ресурсов, чем есть на хосте. Я такого своими глазами не видел, но подзореваю именно это.

Comment: Проверьте ваш сервер на предмет взлома или несанкционированного доступа. И проверьте содержимое `/etc/init.d` чего-странного.

Comment: Вообще если я не ошибаюсь, то ssh чуть выше просит 400 метров памяти. Это ни разу не нормально, и надо действительно посмотреть содержимое /etc/init.d/ssh и попробовать переустановить sshd (только это надо делать очень осторожно, чтобы не оставить сервак без контроля).

Comment: Возможно, вы правы. Дополнил тему скрином. Не могли бы вы дать поверхностный анализ?

Comment: @Димка, это 99% взлом, скрипт по запуску ssh весит < 4кб. Попробуйте скачать вот эту шляпу вместе со всеми sed* файлами для анализа, затем удалить и установить заново ssh.

Comment: Да, вас таки хакнули. Я бы целиком виртуалку откатил к какому-либо бэкапу.

Comment: Ок. Вечером на халявный интернет скачаю. Что такое ssh_key_hack.sh, тоже незнаю. Если любопытно то наверно смогу предоставить. До бэкапирования я еще не дошел. пока нубоват. :))
Спасибо за подсказки.
Значит и второй сервак такая же беда у меня.
Но разговор продолжим в другой теме. Видел я в логах нехорошие вещи с "перлами" в агенте.

Comment: Да, уж...

Я бы все снес и переустановил (с новыми паролями) из проверенных источников.

А еще лучше -- сделал бы свой сервер (физически свой) со статическим IP (правда, на знаю, сколько сейчас стоит статика у провайдеров).

Comment: статика стоит дешево - в пределах 200 руб. за ай пи адрес.

Comment: @avp если для расшаривания в сети, то лучше арендовать дедик. Но если самому дедик поддерживать, то надо разбираться в никсах. А если нуб в никсах, то платить "бородатому дяде-админу". :) Я вот пользуюсь дедиком за 50$ в месяц и не имею проблем со взломом. Даже небольшую ддос атаку успешно выдержал. Но я в никсах немного разбираюсь - заканчивал курсы системного администрирования Linux, поэтому способен поддерживать сам (хотя с почтовым сервером у меня какие-то траблы - к этому меня жизнь не готовила)..

Answer (score 2):

как уже и обсудили в комментариях, судя по приведённой на картинке информации, машина взломана.

в частности, вместо скрипта запуска `/etc/init.d/ssh` лежит неизвестного происхождения бинарный файл, и разбираться, почему этому бинарному файлу не хватает оперативной памяти, абсолютно бессмысленно.